# Хранение данных в SQLite

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite

Помогите плиз новичку, не могу придумать правильную структуру, как хранить данные. 
Всё, что приходит в голову, выглядит жутко коряво. Приложение на Android Studio, база в SQLite. Задача такая: есть база фамилий, которая может пополняться. И база групп людей, каждая из групп содержит список фамилий из первой базы. Количество фамилий в группе может быть любым. Группы тоже могут добавляться. В итоге нужно иметь возможность получить группы, не содержащие фамилии, кроме выбранных из списка. Как правильно сохранить такую структуру? Ни группу, ни фамилии не поставить в Column, поскольку их количество будет увеличиваться. В какую сторону хотя бы искать решение? Или SQLite плохо подходит для такой задачи? Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Чем обычное отношение многие ко многим, реализуемое по средством дополнительной таблицы, не устраивает?

Comment: @PetSerAl, не устраивало незнанием. Нашел, почитал, всё стало понятно, спасибо за заданный вектор.